# how to convert euc-kr to utf-8 'automatically' in vim?

Tags: vim

I know how to convert it manually like this: `map <F4> :e ++enc=euc-kr <CR> :set fenc=utf-8 <CR> :w ++enc=utf-8 <CR>`.

But, I want to convert automatically by writing conditional-statement inside `.vimrc` file.
So, I wrote the code as below and it didn't work.

```
    if ($fileencoding == "euc-kr")
        ++enc=euc-kr %
        set fenc=utf-8
    endif
```

What was wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to it:

To allow Vim to detect the encoding automatically on `:edit` (so that you don't need to specify `++enc=euc-kr`), you have to adapt your `'filencodings'` (plural!) option, e.g.:

```
:set fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,euc-kr
```

In order to persist the encoding as UTF-8, the following autocmd will adapt the `'fileencoding'` (singluar) for the current buffer:

```
:autocmd BufWritePre * if &l:fileencoding ==# 'euc-kr' | setlocal fileencoding=utf-8 | endif
```

Comment: I don't know why but for me `set fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,euc-kr` and      `autocmd BufEnter * if &l:fileencoding ==# 'euc-kr' | setlocal fileencoding=utf-8 | endif` works. And I added write at the end of autocmd.

Comment: If you want to automatically convert on file _open_, that's fine. My solution would only trigger the conversion on the first `:write`.